# Include some aspx pages in search results (cross-site publishing)

Tags: 2013, search, cross-site-publishing

I have a cross-site publishing set up with a catalog/library in one site collection and a user/publishing site in another site collection.

Documents and links come through the cross-site publishing service and I am able to perform searches on terms in either the metadata data or the content, for example, a description column or in the body of a doc or pdf. That is all working well.

I also want to be able to put web part pages into my shared document library. **This is where the trouble starts.** However content in the content editor webparts of those pages don't show up in the search results.

I found [this document](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-content-to-be-searchable-d7ba92db-8618-43fe-87ee-adf03d973062#__toc355013926) with instructions on how to include .aspx pages in search results. Go to Site Settings > Site Admin > Search and offline availability. When I turn it on to always include .aspx pages I **do** start getting the contents of web part pages, but I also start getting a bunch of other pages I don't want, for example, edit and view forms in the hidden Forms directory.

How can I say, "I want any aspx pages and their content in this one library, but don't include all the site infrastructure pages."?

For example, include MySharedLibrary, but exclude docsethomepage.aspx?